# Загрузка файлов Yii

Tags: yii

Для загрузки изображений на сайте пользовался этим http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/form.file.upload . Но удается поменять расширение, например script.php на script.png и успешно загрузить файл на сервер. Что можно сделать для предотвращения подобного.

Comment: @Михаил1992, можно попробовать определить mime-type по содержимому и проверить содержимое на открывающий тег php. Но только скажите, какова вероятность того, что png-файл выполнится на сервере как php?

Comment: Вероятность минимальна. Просто пытаюсь обезопасить свой ресурс от взлома. Считаю, что если удается сделать подобное - то это не есть хорошо. Проверка на открываюший тег не всегда может помочь, это не обязательно может быть php-скрипт. А вы бы как оценили вероятность взлома сайта подобным образом?

Comment: @Михаил1992, как околонулевую. Нужен как минимум дебил-админ, благодаря которому либо все файлы будут исполняться, либо будет возможность переименовать файлы.

Comment: спасибо за совет. А разве файл на сервере не может выполниться без постороннего вмешательства?

Comment: Наверное, глупый вопрос задал) Просто делаю для себя и стараюсь всеми путями обезопасить сайт от взлома) еще раз спасибо за быстрый ответ.

Comment: mime/type тоже не безопасен. Его браузер заполняет. А вот через imagemagick прогнать это да.

Comment: @dimka3210 не "прочесть заголовок mime-type", а "определить mime-type"

Comment: очень подробная инструкция на эту тему. http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/07/yii.html